# bundler, command not found

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler, rbenv

I wanna use the bundler, but after I installed rbenv, ruby and bundler, it still tells me command not found.

```
$ rbenv version
2.2.3 (set by /Users/khlee/.rbenv/version)
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.5
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.12.5
1 gem installed
$ rbenv rehash
$ bundle install
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute below command and check list of gem in gemset:

```
rbenv gemset list
```

May be budler gem is not installed in current gemset.